# convert a csv file to proto format

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, protocol-buffers, proto

is there a way to convert a csv file to proto(protobuf) in python.
I searched but didn't find pertinant ressources.

this is a portion of an example I found in Go:

> ```
>  func WriteProtoToFile(filepath string, allTransactions []*TransactionJsonType) error {    
>   outFile, err := os.OpenFile(filepath,
>   os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)  if err != nil {         return
>   err     }
>
>   for _, item := range allTransactions {
>       convertedItem := toProtoTransaction(item)
>       encodedData, err := proto.Marshal(convertedItem)
>       if err != nil {
>           return err
>       }
>
>       // writing the length of the encoded item before writing the data
>       buf := make([]byte, 4)
>       binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buf, uint32(len(encodedData)))
>       if _, err := outFile.Write(buf); err != nil {
>           return err
>       }
>
>       // writing the actual transaction item to the file
>       if _, err := outFile.Write(encodedData); err != nil {
>           return err
>       }
>   }
>
>   return nil
> }
> ```

but I'm looking to find how to do it in python.
Thank you!

Comment: I can not program Go, could you explain if you would like to setup the .proto file based on the csv file or do you have the .proto definition and want to add the data from the csv file to the protobuf messages?

Comment: thank you for your response:

I would like to know if I'm able to convert a .csv file example:
Name; colour; type
dog ;  black; type2
cat ;  brown; type3
fish;  blue; type4

to a .proto file with a simple command or program(in python or if there is other language)
in my case I will work with huge data, so that command/program should adapt to my csv file.
thank you.

Comment: You would have to write such functionality yourself.

Comment: thank you, I thought there was a predefined function for that.

Comment: Hello, I want to know if there is a way lo load data from json file to proto using python, I didn't find much information about this case, thank you!